# Spring boot. Request can't reach controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm creating an API with Spring Boot and Spring Security. I already created some basic authentication mechanism. And currently facing some unknown problem with authorization of requests.
Here is my Configuration class:

```
// removed for brevity

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    public SecurityConfiguration(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService,
                                 JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter,
                                 CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenFilter = jwtTokenFilter;
        this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // todo: provide an authenticationProvider for authenticationManager
        /* todo:
            In most use cases authenticationProvider extract user info from database.
            To accomplish that, we need to implement userDetailsService (functional interface).
            Here username is an email.
        * */
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to Stateless
        http = http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    ex.getMessage()
                            );
                        }
                )
                .and();

        // Set permissions and endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/beats/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Used by spring security if CORS is enabled.
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Override @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
    }
}
```

To check if user has rights to access resource, I use info from JWT payload. To do so I have a filter class:

```
// removed for brevity
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenFilter.class);
    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
                          CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (header == null || header.isEmpty() || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            logger.error("Authorization header missing");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        final String token = header.split(" ")[1].trim();
        if (!jwtTokenUtil.validate(token)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(token);
        if (userDetails == null)
            throw new ServletException("Couldn't extract user from JWT credentials");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(
                new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

To represent UserDetails, I've implemented CustomUserDetails and CustomUserDetailsService classes:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private Long userId;
    private Long profileId;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
    private String nickname;
    private String avatar;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private ProfileState profileState;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;

    public static CustomUserDetails fromUserAndProfileToMyUserDetails(Profile profile) {
       CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails();
       customUserDetails.setUserId(profile.getUser().getId());
       customUserDetails.setEmail(profile.getUser().getEmail());
       customUserDetails.setPassword(profile.getUser().getPassword());
       customUserDetails.setProfileId(profile.getId());
       customUserDetails.setFullName(profile.getFullName());
       customUserDetails.setNickname(profile.getNickname());
       customUserDetails.setAvatar(profile.getAvatar());
       customUserDetails.setPhoneNumber(profile.getPhoneNumber());
       customUserDetails.setProfileState(profile.getState());
       return customUserDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return nickname;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);
    private final ProfileRepository profileRepository;
    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(ProfileRepository profileRepository, JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.profileRepository = profileRepository;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Token cannot be null or empty");
        try {
            final String nickname = jwtTokenUtil.getNickname(token);
            Profile profile = profileRepository
                    .findByNickname(nickname)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                            String.format("User: %s not found", token)
                    ));
            logger.info(String.format("Extracted Profile: %s", profile));

            CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = CustomUserDetails.fromUserAndProfileToMyUserDetails(profile);
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList());
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(profile.getType().getValue()));
            customUserDetails.setGrantedAuthorities(authorities);
            return customUserDetails;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Wasn't able to load user `{}`. Exception occurred `{}`", token, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller that I want to access:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/beats")
public class BeatController {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BeatController.class);

    private final BeatService beatService;

    public BeatController(BeatService beatService) {
        this.beatService = beatService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public Object getBeat(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            return beatService.findById(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can't find beat with id " + id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new DefaultResponseDto("failed", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Object getBeats(@RequestParam String filter, @RequestParam String page) {
        try {
            return beatService.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can't find beats");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new DefaultResponseDto("failed", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Object createBeat(@RequestBody BeatDto beatDto) {
        try {
            beatDto.setId(null);
            return beatService.save(beatDto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can't create new Beat");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new DefaultResponseDto("failed", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public Object updateBeat(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody BeatDto newBeat) {
        try{
            BeatDto oldBeat = beatService.findById(id);
            if (oldBeat != null) {
                newBeat.setId(id);
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return  beatService.save(newBeat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new DefaultResponseDto("failed", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public Object deleteBeat(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            return beatService.deleteById(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new DefaultResponseDto("failed", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I make a request, provide it with and correct Authorization header and access token. It gets a user from DB and fetches GrantedAuthority. Last steps are:

1. It sets authentication object in SecurityContext.
2. Goes further in FilterChain.

But it doens't reach controller, and it doens't throw any exceptions. Only responses me with 403. May be I forgot something to setup, or problem might be somewehere else? Guide me please.

Comment: Why are you writing your own `JwtFilter` instead of using the official Spring Security OAuth2 JWT support?

Comment: also `UserDetailsService#loadByUsername` is meant to be used to load a user from a data source after authentication. Not to pass in a token. Your implementation has gotten a lot of things backwards. A filter is used to extract the token, the token is then sent to an authenticationManager that validates the token using some sort of JWTvalidator. After the token is validated, the authentication manager calls the `UserDetailsService` passing in the username to fetch the UserDetails object, then the authentication manager takes that and places it into the security context.

Answer (score 0):

So finally figured out what was the problem. Main advices that helped me here:

1. All methods in CustomUserDetails service that were returning `false` return `true`. (Advice from M. Deinum)
2. Turned on spring framework security logs with: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`.
   This helped me to trace an exception, that FilterChain was throwing.
   Thanks to Marcus Hert da Coregio.

What I changed to fix a problem? First I updated `@RequestMapping` mismatch in BeatController. Stack trace showed me that while it was properly fetching user Role from DB, it failed to match my Role and the one I wrote in Configuration class. By default, it add "ROLE_" prefix before the actual role name we provide. I thought that defining this bean changes this behavior:

```
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
    }
```

Turns out that it doesn't effect to prefixing behavior, so it was adding "ROLE_" before the "ADMIN" role name I provided. Adding "ROLE_" prefix while authenticating request fixed problem:

FROM

```
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(profile.getType().getValue()));
```

TO

```
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + profile.getType().getValue()));
```

Additionally I cleaned build and rebuild the project with gradle. Thanks to all people that helped!