# Use keycloak for only authentication and use custom filter for authorization (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to use keycloak just for authentication and have my own custom filter for authorization. So ideal flow will be: First Keycloak filter authenticates the request and sets authentication object in context. Then my custom filter should run and it should get that existing authentication object, add authorities in that authentication object and set it back in context.

My securityConfig is extending KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
   {
      super.configure(http);
        http
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/","/auth","/auth/logout").csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/",
                "/auth",
                "/password/**",
              "/register/**",
              "/v2/api-docs",
              "/actuator/**",
              "/configuration/ui",
              "/swagger-resources",
              "/configuration/security",
              "/swagger-ui.html",
              "/webjars/**",
              "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
              "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
              "/browser/index.html#",
              "/browser/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, REGISTER).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, CONFIRM).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),context))
//      .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),context), KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class)
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
}
```

It runs KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter first and then my custom filter(JWTAuthorizationFilter) but then it calls KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter agains due to which authentication object is set again and authorities are cleared. (i tried couple of things. current code plus commented line and a few more)

So first of all is it the right way to use keycloak in speing boot application if so then how can i make it work that my filter runs last in the filter chain?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, but make sure it is not registered twice. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296224/spring-boot-request-cant-reach-controller#comment120725162_68296224) for a similar suggestion.

Comment: actually KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter is not in my application i am using a library. is there any solution that no matter how many times it runs somehow i could place my filter at the end of the chain?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the keycloak library, but it looks like it may not be as well maintained currently. I have just successfully tested Spring Security 5.5 against keycloak using the built-in `.oauth2Client(withDefaults())` configuration and it works quite well! So I imagine that `.oauth2Login(withDefaults())` will work as well.

Comment: I know it's late now. Me too tried to resolve the same problem with filter, but I found [easier way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281115/add-additional-role-to-keycloak-authentication-from-outer-source)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing two paradigms together, 1) using keycloak as an authorization server, and 2) attempting to use JWTs for one or both of auth(entication|orization).

See [this recently minted video](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/tv/tanzu-tuesdays/0061/) by Spring Security's Josh Cummings on when to use JWTs, and how to do so with Spring Security 5. Also, check out the [JWT sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) which fully replaces your `JWTAuthenticationFilter` without using the `keycloak-spring-security-adapter`. You can also check out the [OAuth2 Login sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login) for a guide on getting started with social login using Spring Security.

As far as using keycloak specifically, I recommend using built-in capabilities of Spring Security 5, which fully integrates with Keycloak's authorization server, and should accomplish both of your goals simultaneously.

### How To

I am running keycloak using docker with the following command:

```sh
docker run --name keycloak -p 9000:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_VENDOR=h2 -d jboss/keycloak
```

I've also added the following to my host file (e.g. `/etc/hosts`) for testing:

```
127.0.0.1       auth-server
```

After logging into keycloak with `admin:admin`, I set up a realm called `myrealm` and a client called `test-client` with a valid redirect uri of `http://localhost:8080/*`, an additional scope of `resource:read`,  generated a client secret, and finally created a user with credentials.

[TLDR: GitHub example](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-security-keycloak-demo)

To get started, make sure the following dependencies are on the classpath:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

There are two ways to configure the app to use keycloak as an authorization server (provider):

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080

keycloak-server:
  uri: http://auth-server:9000/auth/realms/myrealm
  openid-uri: ${keycloak-server.uri}/protocol/openid-connect

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          test-client:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: test-client
            client-secret: ${TEST_CLIENT_SECRET:your-client-secret}
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: resource:read
        provider:
          keycloak:
            # Configure the provider with keycloak
            authorization-uri: ${keycloak-server.openid-uri}/auth
            token-uri: ${keycloak-server.openid-uri}/token
            user-info-uri: ${keycloak-server.openid-uri}/userinfo
            user-info-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            jwk-set-uri: ${keycloak-server.openid-uri}/certs
            # Alternatively, set issuer-uri (replaces above settings) to use ${keycloak-server.uri}/.well-known/openid-configuration
            # to auto-configure OpenID Connect on startup.
            # issuer-uri: ${keycloak-server.uri}
            # This is required in either case to inform Spring Security about keycloak's username
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: trace
```

The easiest way is to set the `issuer-uri` property above, but this requires the Keycloak server to be running when the app starts up. The explicit configuration is uncommented in the above example.

Here is an example controller to prove it works:

```java
@RestController
public class ExampleController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public Map<String, String> home(@AuthenticationPrincipal DefaultOAuth2User user) {
        return Map.of("message", "You are logged in, " + user.getName() + "!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/token")
    public OAuth2AccessToken token(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("test-client") OAuth2AuthorizedClient testClient) {
        return testClient.getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

This is usually enough to authenticate with keycloak. If you want more fine-grained control of Spring Security, use the following configuration to get started:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                .antMatchers("/token").hasAuthority("SCOPE_resource:read")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Client(withDefaults())
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

### Summary

This example uses Spring Security 5 out of the box support for OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect 1.0 with Keycloak.

**Note** that you do not need a custom filter to obtain the authorities from keycloak, we simply requested that `resource:read` scope be available, and Spring Security works with Keycloak to ensure we have rights to this authority. We are also *not* using JWTs for authentication, and instead we are using standard session management, which is *RECOMMENDED*.

Comment: this phrase helped me : `The easiest way is to set the issuer-uri property above`  thank you.

Comment: I found this while looking for a way to use keycloak as a local "dev" profile stand-in for a cloud based filter+federated-id system, which I have to use in production. It looks like a good option, since it's simple. I'm curious about how it manages to avoid all of that other spring (boot) security configuration I see in places like [the keycloak docs](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.adoc),  baeldung and others like [this blog post](https://sandor.tech/java/spring/2017/06/15/spring-boot-with-keycloak.html) !??

Comment: I only skimmed the blog post, but the reason is because those examples use the `keycloak-spring-security-adapter`. All of the functionality built into that adapter (from the keycloak team) can be replaced by built-in support for OAuth 2.0 in later versions of Spring Security (obviously from the Spring Security team/community), where the OAuth story has been developing in the 5.x line. In 5.6, it's very full featured (and was quite so in previous versions as well).

Comment: thanks for the quick and useful answer - another one for you: I downloaded your example, but how do I actually log in? I was hoping a request at http://localhost:8080/ would redirect me to keycloak's login page, but it 404's  (not 401) albeit with an AccessDeniedException in the console. Searching other examples, I noticed your LoopbackIpRedirectFilter in the formal spring examples, and realized that your "etc/hosts" update in the post above was not a mere nicety. But adding that filter (and debugging to see its being used) I still get the same exception...

Comment: Sorry scratch that - I had forgotten to change the hostname to localhost in the properties. When I did - I got a 400 error due to the redirect, but when I actually removed the loopback redirect filter and followed your original advice, it worked. thanks

Comment: Right. That filter you mentioned is for Spring Authorization Server, not keycloak. *Edit:* Also if you wouldn't mind upvoting this answer. It is pretty clear that outdated ways of integrating with keycloak are still trending highly on Google, and it would be nice to change that.

Comment: +1 - thanks. Still haven't got your example working properly - it seemed like it did. Problem is that since this is all new, the interwebs are littered with the outdated instructions and examples and this answer is the _only_ good doc I can find. Some stuff still unclear: 1: issuer_uri is an alternative to _exactly which_ config properties above 2: how to make this sessionless. 3: how much of what's in the config class is necessary vs demonstrative 4: what is the resource:read scope for 5: is the /etc/hosts necessary, or would this work fine with localhost?

Comment: specifically, my browser hangs on this GET request: `http://auth-server:9000/auth/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&scope=resource:read&state=Ks5Udjdds_0wPaAywpZhrWJPnLzwvzRAwfa-o9QdLMw%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/myclient&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=MkyNAHJrjTtV3waNzplEQ7fOPOIrrLnmZTglUxQQZk4` I'm expecting to see a keycloak login page

Comment: argh - giving up and going back to the old keycloak adapters I think - I tried your project verbatim, (adding my own client-secret), with and without the etc/hosts update, etc. And somehow occasionally the browser redirects to keycloak login, but then I can never get it to work twice... Please include full setup and kc instructions in your github...

Comment: Log an issue using my project’s GitHub Issues with your questions/issues and I’ll take a look. You are clearly doing something different because you have PKCE parameters in your example request above.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak is a standards based solution and has some good token issuing capabilities. You can then use any library you like in your API. Keycloak adapters may not be the best choice.

The main things you are likely to want are:

- Validate JWTs in a standard way
- Take control of authorization and claims
- A well documented solution

A while back I put together some code to show how to take closer control of Spring Boot OAuth handling for scenarios where this is required - in case it gives you some ideas for your own solution:

- [Filter Configuration](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/host/startup/HttpServerConfiguration.java#L46)
- [Custom Authorizer](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/StandardAuthorizer.java)

My code uses the [Nimbus SDK](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens) as an example of an OAuth library with great documentation.